# Associative Array in HTML Form preventing submission

Tags: html, json, vue.js

I have an associative array encoded into an HTML form like so (utilizing Vue)

```
// Code:
<div v-for="(obj, index) in arrFriends" :key="index">
 <input v-for="(postID, friendID, index) in obj" type="hidden" :name="addString(friendID)" :key="index" :value="postID">
</div>

// Example of what type of input this code creates:
<input data-v-496dab8d type="hidden" name="arrFriends[4]" value="10">
```

I might be misunderstanding construction of associative arrays using HTML forms, but when there are inputs of this type, the form submission will only cause a page reload, instead of actually submitting the form.

Hopefully someone can enlighten me on what exactly I'm doing wrong, because from all the documentation I've looked at I can't see why this shouldn't work.

Comment: you may have to add the codes how to submit the form.

Comment: It's a standard HTML form, no utilization of special AJAX code for submission, form method is POST and action is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure of the `object` you are iterating with `v-for`, but from the naming of the variables it seems that you do not use it the correct way. (In my snippets I just work with one `obj`, but it's the same if you iterate over an array that holds **objects**.)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    obj: {
      postId: "postId-1",
      friendId: "friendId-2",
      thirdId: "thirdId-3"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="(postId, friendId, index) in obj"
      :key="index"
    >
      {{ `${ friendId }: ${ postId }` }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can see from the snippet above, that `(postId, friendId, index)` does NOT return the values of `postId`, `friendId` properties of `obj`, rather they are variables that get new values on every iteration:

- `postId` => the value at the current iteration of the `obj`
- `friendId` => the key at the current iteration of the `obj`

If you just want `obj.postId` & `obj.friendId`, then you don't need a `v-for` for iteration of the object:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    obj: {
      postId: "postId-1",
      friendId: "friendId-2",
      thirdId: "thirdId-3"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ `${ obj.friendId } - ${ obj.postId }` }}
</div>
```

Comment: When pushing a new obj to the array, it creates the need for having a second v-for. postID and friendID are not static values, but dynamic, obviously they're given the aforementioned variable names when iterated over, but in the actual object they don't have any consistent name. Here's what the object looks like in Vue devtools ```arrFriends: Array[2] [ 0: Object { 4: "10" }, 1: Object { 15: "10" }]``` I can't format it exactly properly in a comment, but hopefully you can get the idea.